# Replace multiple values using regex

Tags: php, javascript, sublimetext2

I have a multidimensional JSON data set that need multiple values replaced so that I can load my application to the web for some troubleshooting.   The values need to be replaced because they are private records that may identify individuals' protected medical information.  I suck at regex and have yet to be able to do this efficiently.  What is want is to replace the following fields as described in the ():

```
PROV_NAME (Drlastname001, Drfirstname001 with # portion incrementing)
PAT_NAME (Patlname0001 , Patfname0001 with # portion incrementing)
PERS_ID, MRN, ENC_ID, FIN, ORD_ID (random # for each)
HOME_PHONE, CELL_PHONE (random ph #)
CMT_PRSNL (Stflastn0001 , Stffirstn0001  with # portion incrementing)
```

Below is a sample of the JSON dataset with the information manually replace.  My real data set has multiple items for most of the arrays [].  I was trying to do this in Sublime Text but once again I suck at regex.  How can I do this quickly?  PHP, JavaScript, within Sublime Text?

```
{
"TICKLER_ORDERED": {
    "PROVIDER": [
        {
            "PROV_NAME": "Drlastname001, Drfirstname001",
            "PERSON": [
                {
                    "PERS_ID": 234213423,
                    "PAT_NAME": "Patlname0001 , Patfname0001",
                    "MRN": "45246",
                    "HOME_PHONE": "984-435-5673",
                    "CELL_PHONE": "745-547-6544",
                    "OLDEST_ORDER": "/Date(2012-01-03T13:34:28.000-04:00)/",
                    "ENCOUNTERS": [
                        {
                            "ENC_ID": 8854774,
                            "FIN": "78787457",
                            "ORDERS": [
                                {
                                    "ORD_ID": 23423413,
                                    "ORD_NAME": "MA Digital Diagnostic Mammo-Bil/CAD",
                                    "ORD_TYPE": "Radiology",
                                    "ORD_STATUS": "Canceled",
                                    "ORD_PRIORITY": "Routine",
                                    "ORD_DATE": "01/03/2012 13:34",
                                    "DUE_DATE": "01/06/2012 13:00",
                                    "COMMENTS": [
                                        {
                                            "CMT_DISP": "This is a test",
                                            "SEQUENCE": "1",
                                            "CMT_DTTM": "02/04/13 11:40",
                                            "CMT_PRSNL": "Stflastn , Stffirstn"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "CMT_DISP": "This isn't a test",
                                            "SEQUENCE": "2",
                                            "CMT_DTTM": "02/04/13 11:42",
                                            "CMT_PRSNL": "Stflastn0001 , Stffirstn0001"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "ORD_ID": 123234235,
                                    "ORD_NAME": "US Breast Bilateral",
                                    "ORD_TYPE": "Radiology",
                                    "ORD_STATUS": "Canceled",
                                    "ORD_PRIORITY": "Routine",
                                    "ORD_DATE": "01/03/2012 13:34",
                                    "DUE_DATE": "01/06/2012 14:20",
                                    "COMMENTS": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not too sure about whether you can increment a number with a regex replace

Comment: Use json_decode and json_encode, and replace the values once the json has been converted into an object, and convert it back to json after.

Comment: @Isaac You can, but they'll have to pass a function as the second parameter to `.replace()`, which can dynamically return content to replace the matched part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP provides great tools for iterating over an array of JSON data.  As adeneo suggests, json_decode and json_encode will let you convert your data from JSON to a PHP multi-dimensional array, and back to JSON, respectively.  Once you have your data in a PHP array, iterate over that array and use your knowledge of its structure, simple regular expressions (something like '/[0-9]{3}$/'), and counter variables to appropriately increase the indices.

- Edited 6/2/13 for punctuation.

Comment: I did this and it worked fine.  I just didn't want to go through writing 5 levels of loops.  Thank you too @adeneo.